# Difference between PostGIS pgrouting and Lizmap pgrouting

Tags: postgis, routing, lizmap

I'm starting to work with pgrouting.
I know that pgrouting is an extension of PostGIS.
I saw that Lizmap (which I currently work on) provides a module called pgrouting.
Two points are drawn from the GIF on the site and the path is traced from there, based on criteria.
The work I have to do with pgrounting does not concern the insertion of points, but I have to work with already existing points that I will have to load into the database.
I read that pgrouting as an extension of PostGIS allows you to work like this.
I have the impression that this Lizmap module is not necessary for what I need to do. I could work directly from the database and use Lizmap to view the processing performed.
Maybe it confuses me that they have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

- Lizmap Web Application generates dynamically a web map application (PHP/HTML/CSS/JS) with the help of QGIS Server.
- Lizmap PgRouting Module is a module for Lizmap using pgRouting as a dependency. It allows to draw a start point, a end point and also intermediate points (gif has to be updated) on a map then a request is made to the server which returns the route calculated by pgRouting.